# Regex: what does (?! ...) mean?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

The following regex finds text between substrings FTW and ODP.

```
/FTW(((?!FTW|ODP).)+)ODP+/
```

What does the `(?!`...`)` do?

Comment: This is perl-specific (and pcre), is it not?

Comment: @tylerl: It applies to any flavor that supports lookahead: Perl, Python, PHP, .NET, Java, JavaScript, JGSoft, et al.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`(?!regex)` is a [zero-width negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  It will test the characters at the current cursor position and forward, testing that they do **NOT** match the supplied regex, and then return the cursor back to where it started.

The whole regexp:

```
/
 FTW           # Match Characters 'FTW'
 (             # Start Match Group 1
  (             # Start Match Group 2
   (?!FTW|ODP)   # Ensure next characters are NOT 'FTW' or 'ODP', without matching
   .             # Match one character
  )+            # End Match Group 2, Match One or More times
 )             # End Match Group 1
 OD            # Match characters 'OD'
 P+            # Match 'P' One or More times
/
```

So - Hunt for `FTW`, then capture while looking for `ODP+` to end our string.  Also ensure that the data between `FTW` and `ODP+` doesn't contain `FTW` or `ODP`

Comment: +1 for correctly explaining how it's being used in the supplied regex.

Answer (score 20):

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions):

> A **zero-width negative look-ahead assertion**. For example `/foo(?!bar)/` matches any occurrence of "`foo`" that isn't followed by "`bar`". Note however that look-ahead and look-behind are NOT the same thing. You cannot use this for look-behind.
>
> If you are looking for a "bar" that isn't preceded by a "`foo`", `/(?!foo)bar/` will not do what you want. That's because the `(?!foo)` is just saying that the next thing cannot be "`foo`"--and it's not, it's a "bar", so "`foobar`" will match. You would have to do something like `/(?!foo)...bar/` for that. We say "like" because there's the case of your "`bar`" not having three characters before it. You could cover that this way: `/(?:(?!foo)...|^.{0,2})bar/` . Sometimes it's still easier just to say:

```
if (/bar/ && $` !~ /foo$/)
```

Comment: For negative look-behind, if the parser supports it you can just use `(?<!stuff)` to check that "stuff" doesn't match before the current point. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html for more info.

Comment: "Google is your friend" if you have some idea what search terms to use.  Anyway, didn't you mean to link to this fragment? http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions

Comment: in this case i think its pretty easy to know to google for regex documentation. yes, thanks for link correction

Answer (score 7):

It means "not followed by...". Technically this is what's called a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in that you can peek at what's ahead in the string without capturing it. It is a class of zero-width assertion, meaning that such expressions don't capture any part of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

Regex

```
/FTW(((?!FTW|ODP).)+)ODP+/
```

matches first FTW immediately followed neither by FTW nor by ODP, then all following chars up to the first ODP (but if there is FTW somewhere in them there will be no match) then all the letters P that follow.

So in the string:

FTWFTWODPFTWjjFTWjjODPPPPjjODPPPjjj

it will match the bold part

FTWFTWODPFTWjj**FTWjjODPPPP**jjODPPPjjj

Comment: Slight error in your logic there, Since the lookahead assertion is inside the `+`'ed match group, it matches any text between FTW....ODP that doesn't conatin either FTW or ODP inside of it.

Comment: @gnarf is right: greedy or not, this regex will never match more than one occurrence of "FTW" or "ODP".

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I'm fixing this to avoid confusion of the future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

'?!' is actually part of '(?! ... )', it means whatever is inside must NOT match at that location.