# How do I catch strings that don't start with "ajax/" using regex for CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I'm working on some routes for my CodeIgniter application, and I need to declare a 'catch-all'/except one regular expression. Any route that *doesn't* start with 'ajax/' should be redirected to the 'main'-router. Like so:

```
$route['regexmagichere'] = "main";
```

So this is definetly way beyond my regex skills and I need some help. The regex should return true on *all* strings that don't start with 'ajax/', like so:

```
$string_one = "ajax/someotherstuffhere";
$string_two = " ajax/test";
$string_three = "somestuffhere";
```

Here $string_one would be the only one returning false. Thanks for your time!

Comment: If there is an order in the execution of the routes, you could name the more specific routes in the beginning while adding a *catchall* route at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
^((?!ajax).*)
```

Comment: From the manual: Note that the apparently similar pattern (?!foo)bar does not find an occurrence of "bar" that is preceded by something other than "foo"; it finds any occurrence of "bar" whatsoever, because the assertion (?!foo) is always TRUE when the next three characters are "bar". A lookbehind assertion is needed to achieve this effect.

Comment: @Question Mark - Not true in this case the `^` anchors to the start of the string, then `(?!ajax)` ensures that the first characters are not `"ajax"` proceeding onward to capture the whole string with the `(.*)`

Comment: There is a difference between `(?!foo)bar` and `(?!foo).*` - this solution will work fine, although the capturing group probably isn't necessary - using `^(?!ajax).*` is fine.

Answer (score 4):

To be litereal to your request.  A regexp that returns true for all strings that don't start with `ajax/`:

```
^(?!ajax/).*
```

You might need to escape the `/` as `\/`.  `(?!)` is a negative look-ahead expression explained [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371149/regex-what-does-mean/1371194#1371194).

Comment: Just wondering, if this is just a boolean match, is the `*` necessary?

Comment: Likely not... the `.` probably isn't necessary either, but I didn't test, and wasn't aware if codeigntor does anything funky if you don't consume the whole string in the route match...

Answer (score -2):

I think `^(?<!ajax)\/` will do the trick.

I stress "think"!

Comment: Using a look-behind at the start of the string seems silly...  This would match any string starting with `/`

Comment: the look behind is on the /, and matching /someotherstuffhere satisfies the question's criteria no?

Comment: Have you specifically tested this expression on CodeIgniter? Does it include a slash at the start of all paths? Will the slash need escaping?

Comment: codeignitor uses preg_match using # delimiters, so no, the slash doesn't need escaping, my bad, can't hurt though. There is no leading slash so this expression would never fall for gnarf's comment above.