# Regex for alphanumeric characters but all of which are not zero

Tags: javascript, regex

Conditions:-

1. Total length = 12
2. First letter = A
3. Second letter = B
4. Rest of the 10 characters = Numbers or alphabets
5. Rest of the 10 characters cannot be equal to 0000000000

Valid:-

1. AB1234567890
2. ABABABABABAB
3. AB1234HIJ001

Invalid:-

1. AB0000000000
2. AB0
3. AA1234567890

I have come up with this regex: `'^[A-A][B-B][A-Z0-9]{10}$'`. It prevents Invalid #2 and #3. But I'm having a hard time with Invalid #1. I know that to prevent all characters from being 0, I need to use `'^0+$'`. But how do I combine these two expressions?

Comment: Why not do the check for all zeros with a plain JavaScript string comparison? It's likely to be easier to write and to read than a regex solution.

Comment: it won't be possible with regex

Comment: @Thomas Because I have an array of regexes which I'm using as eligible formats for an input. I want my Javascript code to match the formats from the array, instead of breaking down the input and checking the format.

Comment: @Vulwsztyn Not true. Very definitely possible as a regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371149/regex-what-does-mean) to accomplish this: `(?!0{10})`.

```
^[A-A][B-B](?!0{10})[A-Z0-9]{10}$
           ^^^^^^^^^
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/DDUEWN/1)

By the way, you don't need `[A-A][B-B]`. Just `AB` does exactly the same.

Comment: Came up with almost exactly the same thing `^AB(?!0{10})[A-Z0-9]{10}$`

Comment: One could alternatively use a *positive lookahead*: `AB(?=.*[^0])[A-Z0-9]{10}$`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Probably, but [not that one](https://regex101.com/r/7eWPyp/1) :)

Comment: Good catch! Let's make that `^AB(?=.*[^0\r\n])[A-Z0-9]{10}$`. As I often advise others, "always test"!